# Calculating dependency list, given multiple subdependency lists

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of elements: A, B, C, ...
Then, I create multiple dependency lists, for example like this: B->C->H->X, A->C->I

Given the previous information, I want to calculate a dependency list, of all the elements.

The problem is, the solution might not be without conflicts (they should be rare!). For example given those lists: A->B, B->A, A->B I'd like the solution to be A->B, because the error is less than B->A.

I thought about the following algorithms:

- Calculate the ranking like in formula 1: each list is a race, so: first place gets a certain amount of points, second gets less and so forth. The problem is how to weight and normalize those points, ... I'm not sure how to do that correctly.
- Maybe like the ATP rating of tennis ;) But then again, more occurrences lead to more weight in the end, which doesn't give good results. Because for example: A->C, A->C, A->C, A->B, B->C should result in A->B->C. The ATP algorithm probably gives C a high ranking, so the solution may be A->C->B, which is not what I want.
- Store O(n^2) relations and a count of occurrences. For example, given this list: A->B->C, store A->B(1), A->C(1), B->C(1). Then if a second list gets added: B->C then the resulting data will be A->B(1), A->C(1), B->C(2). Using those informations, calculate the ranking. I think this way I have the most complete information available, the problem is now "only" to calculate the dependency list over all elements :) The downside is of course the data amount you have to store.

My personal favourite is the last one, but I'm very hesitant because of the complexity. I'd really like to have a simple algorithm and O(n) data storage. That's why I'm asking here, hoping for better solutions or some input.

**Update**

- The chosen dependencies are not entirely random. It's more strict than random voting. The dependencies should actually converge to a single solution where conflicts are rare. So, arrow's impossibility theorem doesn't apply here 100% (thx @Heuster)
- Expected number of elements: less than 100
- Expected number of lists: slowly grow over time, less than 1000
- Maximum length of dependency list: less than 100
- All the elements are contained somwhere inside a list

Comment: There is a whole branch of game theory studying these problems. This is about *voting*: if you let a group of people independently order a set of candidates, what is a fair order for the group as a whole? Turns out that it is impossible to find a "perfect" system. See [Arrow's impossibility theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow's_impossibility_theorem).

Comment: @Heuster: Cool thx. Is there some sort of weaker statement, if the conflicts are rare? Because those depedencies are not entirely random. Maybe an algorithm to sort out the neglectable conflicts?

Comment: @duedl0r I don't really know, I'm not at all an expert in this field. Just meant to provide some specific search terms :-)

Comment: @duedl0r: You need to define "error" to make this a specific question. Number of edges in the input that are not obeyed by the resulting DAG?

Comment: @NiklasB.: I haven't really thought about it.. but what you're suggesting makes sense.

Comment: How many nodes do you have, how many lists, and what is the total and maximum length of input lists?

Comment: @NiklasB.: There are less than 100 nodes. Lists might get a little bit bigger, because they grow (slowly) over time. On the positive side, newly added lists should be near the perfect solution and conflicts should be rarer.

Comment: And do all chains contain all the nodes?

Comment: Yes, all the nodes are used somewhere in those lists.

Comment: This is a graph theory problem. Your dependency list can be modelled as a graph with each element representing a vertex and each pair of dependency represented by a directed edge. A conflict of dependency is precisely the presence of a directed cycle in the graph, and resolving conflict should be modelled as removing minimum number of edges to turn the graph acyclic (has no cycles). The first part of detecting cycle in a directed graph has been discussed in StackOverflow under a different question, try search for "Detecting cycles in a directed graph". The second part... not sure yet.

Comment: in addition to above, once your graph is acyclic (i.e. conflict or cyclic dependency removed), getting your master dependency list is equivalent of doing a "topological sort" of your directed graph. You can find algorithm here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: @firemana: thx, I think I'll ask a new question about the second part and then put it in here. I guess I can get better results with a new, precise question.